# Find Longest Word in String

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm working with R Hadoop. I have a string which I mapreduced setting each word as a key and its length as the associated value. How do I find the longest word from within mapreduce?

```
Sys.setenv("HADOOP_CMD"="/home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hadoop")
Sys.setenv("HADOOP_STREAMING"="/home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.8.1.jar")
Sys.setenv("HADOOP_HOME"="/home/hadoop/hadoop")
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/latest")

library(rhdfs)
library(rmr2)
hdfs.init()

line = "It's Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious!
Even though the sound of it
Is something quite atrocious
If you say it loud enough
You'll always sound precocious
Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious!"

to.dfs(line, output='/home/m072040031/small_doc.txt',
       format="text")

wordcount = function(input,
                     output,
                     pattern = '[[:punct:][:space:][:digit:]]+'){
  mapreduce(input = input,
            output = output,
            input.format= "text",
            map = function(k,
                           lines){
              v = unlist(strsplit(lines,
                                   split= pattern))
              keyval(v,
                     nchar(v))},
            reduce = function(word,
                              count){
              keyval(word,
                     count)}
            )
}

wordcount("/home/m072040031/small_doc.txt",
          output = "/home/m072040031/small_doc_wc.RData")

info=from.dfs("/home/m072040031/small_doc_wc.RData")

info
```

Comment: What do you want if there are two or more words that have the same number of characters? Do you want the location of the word(s) or the word(s)?

Comment: the longest words themselves

Comment: Apologies, not familiar with `mapreduce` / Hadoop. If it would help, I could write a regular function that will return the longest words. If `keyval` creates a list I can format the function to create a list and get the words from the list.

Comment: Using `stringi` outside of Hadoop and your regex for splitting. It will probably be faster than any base R solution:

`longest_words <- function(line){
  split <- stri_split(line, regex = "\\n|\\r|[[:punct:]]|[[:space:]]")[[1]]
  split[which(nchar(split) == max(stri_length(split)))]
}`